# Exchange - allow all users to see each others agenda

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I want to make a small script that all users can see each others agenda.

But the `'$user.alias'` is where i fail
I'm still learning Exchange scripting, at the moment I use Exchange 2010.

```
$mailboxen = get-mailbox | get-mailboxstatistics | where {$_.totalitemsize -ge 1mb} 

foreach ($user in $mailboxen) { 
Write-Host -ForegroundColor green "Setting permission for $($user.alias)..." 
Set-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity "$($user.alias):\calendar" -User 
Default -AccessRights Reviewer 
}
```

Comment: Describe the problem you are having. Don't make us guess. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use

```
$mailboxes = Get-Mailbox
$mailboxes | ForEach {Set-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity ([string]($_.PrimarySmtpAddress) + ":\Calendar") -User Default -AccessRights Reviewer}
```

With what you've used Get-MailboxStatistics doesn't return either the primarysmtp or the alias, so your variable $mailboxen won't contain it either.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've joined two different scripts together as `get-mailboxstatistics` isn't needed:

```
$mailboxen = Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited

foreach ($user in $mailboxen) { 
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Setting permission for $($user.alias)..."
    Set-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity "$($user.alias):\calendar" -User Default -AccessRights Reviewer
}
```